# URL rewrite Pattern in iis 10

Tags: iis, iis-10

I'm using Asp.Net web forms.In my URL I don't want to expose after the character '?'. I want the regular expression pattern to achieve this using IIS 10. I have tried this "Security(.+)$" but it doesn't work.

From this: `www.some.com/Security/login.aspx?name=dfdf`

To this: `www.some.com/Security/login.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to expose query string.

1.you should redirect any request to **www.some.com/Security/login.aspx?name=dfdf** to **www.some.com/Security/login.aspx**.

2.Then you have to rewrite request from **www.some.com/Security/login.aspx** back to **www.some.com/Security/login.aspx?name=dfdf**

Just keep in mind that, this rule can only rewrite back to static query string ?name=dfdf.

If you need to need to dynamic rewrite the URL, then you may need to add a custom request header to save the query string. So that backend server will know where should it rewrite back.

```
   <rules>
                <rule name="redirect rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/Security/login.aspx\?(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="Security/login.aspx" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rewrite back" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/Security/login.aspx$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="Security/login.asp?name=dfdf" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
```